# Is there a way to enable Ubuntu Keyboard shortcuts in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys

I like to have default Ubuntu shortcuts available in my Kubuntu,
but I don't want to assign them all manually, I mean a way to import them from Ubuntu.

For Example I want <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which opens the Terminal
or <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad</kbd> to resize windows.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to assign them manually. As far as I know there is no such possibility to import the Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts directly.

But I had a similar problem creating a keyboard shortcut(ksc) to open my konsole with the ksc <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> so I started searching and came up with the following solution:

1. Open a terminal and enter following commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
   ```
2. Create a file named .xbindkeysrc in your home folder

   ```
   kate ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
3. Copy and paste following content to open your terminal with the ksc <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and after that save and close the file.

   ```
   "konsole"
   Control+Alt + t
   ```
4. Start xbindkeys

   ```
   xbindkeys
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to find out if the ksc is working
6. If the command is working add xbindkeys to Autostart

   ```
   cd ~/.kde/Autostart/
   ln -s /usr/bin/xbindkeys xbindkeys
   ```

If you want to find out the name of a key, just enter following command in the terminal

```
xbindkeys -k
```

and press any key or combination.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier solution using KDE native configuration tools here:

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=97493

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! To improve your answer, could you add a summary of the solution you found?