# How can I get Kubuntu to use my Multimedia keys?

Tags: kubuntu, multimedia, shortcut-keys

I have tried to get Kubuntu to use my multimedia keys, and I cannot figure out how to do this. This feature is default in Ubuntu and in Linux Mint. They just work. I have followed the KUbuntu wiki post on Multimedia keys. I tried to enable Multimedia maps with `xmodmap`. It did not work. I tried to use the KDE GUI and could not seem to make the function I wanted work.

The functions I am trying to get to work are

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> = skip song
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> = previous song
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> = stop
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>F9</kbd> = play/pause.

I know this is possible because it worked in Ubuntu and in Mint, but it does not work in Kubuntu. I have submitted a bug report on this issue.

**Disclaimer:** I am using Kubuntu 12.04

I have looked at this post, but [Is there a way to enable Ubuntu Keyboard shortcuts in Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80205/is-there-a-way-to-enable-ubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts-in-kubuntu) do not know what to call the keys in that program.

Answer (score 3):

KDE assigns keyboard shortcuts on a per app basis. If you are using Amarok, for example, click on the `Settings` menu item and then the third item under that `Configure shortcuts`. This will open a dialogue with all the Amarok actions and 3 separate shortcut options for each action.